# WSO2 API Manager and IP Filtering

Tags: api, wso2

For the life of me, I can't find any information on this, including the WSO2 site.  Can I lock down an access token to a specific IP address or IP address range?  For instance, if Client A subscribes to an API in WSO2 API Store, and somehow, Client B gains access to the access token (maybe a disgruntled employee of Client A, for instance), I'd like to lock down usage of that access token in the API Manager so that ONLY Client A can make calls with it.  Can this be done, and how might I go about configuring it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In API Manager 1.4.0 we have domain restrictions for access tokens. This can be done at the time of generating the access token for a subscribed API. Domain/s can be specified by clicking on the 'edit' link next to 'Allowed Domains'.

More detail are available here:
http://dinushasblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/domain-restrictions-for-api-invocations.html